# Show that if $F$ is closed and $K$ is compact then $F \cap K$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I said that $F$ is closed
and $K$ is compact. Since $K$ is compact, $K$ is closed for sure.
Now since both $F$ and $K$ are closed, their intersection is closed too.
Now I'm not able to show that their intersection is compact.

Comment: A closed subset of a compact space is compact....  Note that $F\cap K$ is a subset of $K$.

Comment: Are $F$ and $K$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? Because it sounds like you are using the Heine-Borel theorem, which isn't always true for arbitrary metric space.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $\{ U_i \}$ is any open cover of $F \cap K$, then $\{ U_i \} \cup (F^c)$ is an open cover of $K$. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

Since one of your tags is "real analysis," I will describe a hint to prove that $K\cap F$ is sequentially compact. If $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $K\cap F$, then in particular it is a sequence in $K$, so by compactness of $K$, there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ and a point $x\in K$, such that $x_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty} x$. What do you need to show to finish the proof that $K\cap F$ is compact?